# Can't install .ipk files on router

Tags: linux, networking, router

I am following this tutorial: [WRT54GL v1.1 wired IEEE 802.1x client TTLS PAP:(surfnet / eduroam / securew2 wpa_supplicant, EAPOL TX RX)](https://forum.openwrt.org/viewtopic.php?pid=92932)  to setup my Linksys 160NL router with authentication. I have flashed the router with OpenWrt Backfire 10.03.1. and it's packages are located [here](http://downloads.openwrt.org/backfire/10.03.1/atheros/packages/).

At step3 it says I should secure copy and install the following packages onto my router :

```
opkg install nano 
opkg install ntpclient 
opkg install wpa-supplicant
```

I coppied the following packages to the router's /tmp folder (using pscp.exe):

```
nano_2.2.6-1_atheros.ipk                          --> renamed to nano.ipk
ntpclient_2007_365-4_atheros.ipk                  --> renamed to ntpclient.ipk
wpa-supplicant_20111103-2_atheros.ipk             --> renamed to supplicant.ipk
libncurses_5.7-2_atheros.ipk (dependency of nano) --> renamed to libncurses
```

Then I tried installing them, by connecting with Putty to the router and executing:

```
opkg install libncurses.ipk
```

I got the following error:

```
 * pkg_hash_fetch_best_installation_candidate: Packages for libncurses found, 
   but incompatible with the architectures configured
 * opkg_install_cmd: Cannot install package libncurses.
```

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** I was downloading the packages from the wrong package folder. I thought I should download them from the "atheros" folder, but those aren't the right ones. Packages from the folder "[ar71xx](http://downloads.openwrt.org/backfire/10.03.1/ar71xx/packages/)" installed without any problem. **I still don't know why that is. If someone can offer an explanation I would be very thankful.**

Comment: If you found the answer, do add it! :) Also, get used to `vi`. :P

Answer (score 2):

Well now, if you're asking "why", the answer is simple:
Because that's your routers CPU. As linked [here](http://wiki.openwrt.org/toh/linksys/wrt160nl), even the firmware base image comes from that directory. It should even be in the image's filename.

Backfire is outdated, by the way. The current stable is "Attitude Adjustment" (12.09):

- [openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wrt160nl-jffs2-factory.bin](http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wrt160nl-jffs2-factory.bin)
- [openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wrt160nl-jffs2-sysupgrade.bin](http://downloads.openwrt.org/attitude_adjustment/12.09/ar71xx/generic/openwrt-ar71xx-generic-wrt160nl-jffs2-sysupgrade.bin)